Why are 'bluetoothd' and 'configd' using so much memory?
I have a MacBook Air M2 with 8 GB memory, running Ventura 13.6. I've recently been getting a warning about using too much application memory, but at first I just chalked it up to using memory-intensive apps like Adobe Illustrator. I started getting the issue just with a few Safari tabs and miscellaneous apps open though, and after looking at Activity Monitor again I realized bluetoothd and configd are the issue (kind of dumb of me, I had noticed the high memory usage before, but I just ignored it). They're using 23 GB and 15 GB of memory respectively; I don't understand how it works, but I'm guessing they're contributing to the 33 GB swap usage, which seems to be way too much.
There've been posts/questions about this issue, like this StackExchange post. I also found some Reddit posts on similar issues where some commenters have suggested powering off and powering on the computer: here and here. I'm going to do that and see if that fixes it, but I'm wondering what's the reasoning behind what's going on.
Thanks in advance!


Is there some reason why you are still running an outdated version of macOS? If you’re triggering a memory leak, updating to Sonoma may fix it.

This is almost certainly the result of a bug in the OS. As @LincD. says, your first step in this case should be to upgrade to the latest macOS. This will almost certainly fix it. If not, let us know and we can help you start a debugging session.

Well, at least get onto the current Ventura, 13.6.9.

Thanks all for the help, I ended up updating to Sonoma and it seems to be better now. A more general question I had - apologies if it's silly - what is the significance of the memory used value? Should I be concerned about using memory-intensive apps and/or seeing the memory pressure turn yellow?
